# Infopath - Instruct concat not to strip out existing formatting

Tags: sharepoint, infopath

I should like to append a string to the end of a Rich Text Box, on a button press.

I have configured the button to "set a field's value" on press, with the value being configured as:

```
concat(richTextBox, string_to_append)
```

However the concat function removes any existing formatting on the text in the text box.

- Is there any way to tell concat() to preserve existing formatting

OR

- Is there some way to convert the strings to byte arrays, then join and convert back?

(Using Infopath 2010 to edit a Sharepoint form.)